# TimeMachine and an External HFS + NTFS HDD

Tags: time-machine

Can I partition my external HDD into 2 HFS + NTFS? and use HFS+ partition for TimeMachine backup. I already lost my info once in this way, this is why I have to ask now, before doing some stupid things again. The NTFS partition is for Ubuntu and Windows machine from my office, at home I am using 10.6.8

Comment: A word of advice: never use your backup HD for something else. HD are way cheaper than data loss.

Comment: I know, but I already have an 1TB external drive, in my country, they are very expensive

Comment: Yeah, Gio is right, don't use your backup drive for anything but backups. It will increase the likelihood of that drive crashing.

Comment: With Lion or greater, a JHFSX volume to which Time Machine backs up may be a sparse bundle disk image on an NTFS volume – [Backup to NTFS … Restore from NTFS](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57082/8546) – where the device number of the JHFSX volume is *higher* than the number of the physical disk that is used for NTFS. In that way you can use Time Machine with NTFS alone on a single disk. As the question is specifically for two file systems on a single disk, my vote goes to David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Machine needs a mountable HFS+ partition; it couldn't care less how large that partition is relative to the overall size of the drive.

But I agree with Gio's comment; drives are cheap, so I'd suggest getting multiple drives.