# Whole system backup boot-camp included

Tags: backup, time-machine, bootcamp

I have access to a 1TB drive.
I need to backup the MacBook which I have access to, which has a version of Windows on it via Bootcamp.

I have learned that Time Machine does not keep track of windows partitions.

How can I do a whole-systems backup of the device, bootcamp partitions included?

Answer (score 1):

I would use winclone to back up the windows separate from the Mac.

- [Backing up a Boot Camp partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/backing-up-a-boot-camp-partition)

The reasons are for file system differences and the simple fact that you have to back up the entire terabyte each time if you just image the drive using disk utility.

But you can also image the whole drive with disk utility - block by block - and have an image of it.  That’s free and included with macOS.

Comment: Winclone can make a compressed full and incremental backups of a Bootcamp volume to a macOS volume that Time Machine can then backup.

Comment: @DavidAnderson but the consensus is, at least so far, to format the drive for Time Machine